# Unable to call .dict() method on custom Pydantic models (exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict')

Tags: pydantic, python-dataclasses, python-3.11

I am new to dataclasses/Pydantic models and I am running into an issue elaborated below.
I have defined two `pydantic models`
`Role`s and `SubRole`s such that `Role` model contains a `set` of `SubRole`s.

```
"""
Module contains all the models.
"""

# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods


import typing
import pydantic


class RoleBaseClass(pydantic.BaseModel):  # pylint: disable=no-member
    """
    Base class for all the models.
    """
    name: str = pydantic.Field(regex=r"^\w+$")

    def __hash__(self: typing.Self) -> int:
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.name == other.name


class SubRole(RoleBaseClass):
    """
    SubRole model.
    """

class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    """
    Role model.
    """
    subroles: set[SubRole] = pydantic.Field(default=set())

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        base_str: str = super().__str__()
        cls_name: str = self.__class__.__name__
        return f"{cls_name}({base_str})"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    data0 = Role(
        name="aws0",
    )

    data1 = Role(
        name="aws1",
        subroles=set(
            [
                SubRole(name="aws1sub1"),
                SubRole(name="aws1sub2"),
            ]
        ),
    )

    data2 = Role(
        name="aws1",
        subroles=set(
            [
                SubRole(name="aws2sub1"),
                SubRole(name="aws2sub2"),
            ]
        ),
    )

    print(data0)
    print(data1.subroles)
    print(data1 == data2)
    
    # Below line fails with TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
    print(data2.dict())
```

everything works apart from calling `Role().dict()` method which fails with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` error, `traceback` below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 72, in <module>
    print(data2.dict())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 449, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.dict
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 868, in _iter
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 794, in pydantic.main.BaseModel._get_value
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Could anyone suggest the mistake I made, also any further improvement to the code.

Cheers,
DD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the `set()` object is not hashable. ***Here are 3 solutions of various elegance:***

##### 1. A quick dirty fix is to use a list instead:

> *You can enforce deduplication via a validator if needed.*

```
    subroles: list[SubRole]
```

##### 2. Another quick fix is to use the argument [`models_as_dict=False`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#serialising-self-reference-or-other-models) when serializing to `json`:

> *Note: this will only work to json, see next solution for serializing to a dict...*

```
print(data2.json(models_as_dict=False))
```

##### 3. To serialize your set to a `dict()`, use the `self._iter()` method, as follows:

> Note: `self._iter()` is wrapped by the `self.dict()` method, so you are basically accessing the underlying functionality directly.

```py
my_dict = dict(data2._iter(to_dict=False))
print(my_dict)
```

##### A proper solution: Override `__getitem__()`

This goes a bit beyond my scope of understanding, but this github conversation thread would be a good place to start:
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/380#issuecomment-459352718. *(Note, this would probably be the best solution for you.)*

#### Extra Stuff:

1. You should be using [`default_factory=set`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) instead, since `default=list|set` will create problems for you because of [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments):

```
class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    """
    Role model.
    """
    subroles: list[SubRole] = pydantic.Field(default_factory=list)
```

2. Presently, `Role.json(models_as_dict=False)` will give you a list of dictionary objects.

```
{"name": "aws1", "subroles": [{"name": "aws2sub2"}, {"name": "aws2sub1"}]}
```

If you want a list of attributes, use a [custom `json_encoder`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) like so:

```
class Role(RoleBaseClass):
    """
    Role model.
    """
    subroles: typing.Set[SubRole] = pydantic.Field(default_factory=set)

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            SubRole: lambda x: x.name,
        }
```

This will give you a list of names:

```
{"name": "aws1", "subroles": ["aws2sub1", "aws2sub2"]}
```